# Finding mean of HSV converted video feed

Tags: c++, matlab, split, mean, hsv

This is expected behavior of my code:

"I am supposed to get a RGB2HSV converted video and original video from my main program and design a function that may find mean of all H, S and V values and generate 1*3 matrix for each frame. "

This is actually to do classification of objects between fire and non fire using PCA. I have done feature extraction in MATLAB and have PCA Coefficients decalred in c++ code in visual studio. Apparently the code is error free but when I debugg to run it, it gives error that can be seen in attached photo.

Also, the rest of the code has been executed properly without error.
Where is the problem. attaching my code

```
void pca_decide(Mat &Threshdimg , Mat &Original)
{
//declare master pca matrix

double  pca_data[9] = { -0.5398, -0.4189, 0.7302, -0.0365, 0.8782, 0.4768, 0.8410, -0.2307, 0.4893 };
Mat pca = Mat(3, 3, CV_32F, pca_data);

//declaring mean fire hsv values multiplied with pca in matlab
double fire_pca_data[3] = { 0.7375, -0.0747,0.6608 };
Mat fire_pca = Mat(1, 3, CV_32F, fire_pca_data);

//declaring mean non-fire hsv values multiplied with pca in matlab
double  nfire_pca_data[3] = { 0.4389,-0.0874, 0.6240 };
Mat nfire_pca = Mat(1, 3, CV_32F, nfire_pca_data);

//generating current image hsv values in euclidean space

Mat image_pca;
double  rows = Threshdimg.rows;
double  cols = Threshdimg.cols;

vector<Mat> hsv_planes;
split(Threshdimg, hsv_planes);
Mat h = hsv_planes[0]; // H channel h is a 2D matrix
Mat s = hsv_planes[1]; // S channel
Mat v = hsv_planes[2]; // V channel

Scalar h_mean_image = sum(h)/ (rows*cols); // here I need to sum all the rows and columns 
Scalar s_mean_image = sum(s)(rows*cols);
Scalar v_mean_image = sum(v)(rows*cols);
Scalar  HSV_mean_data[3] = { h_mean_image, s_mean_image, v_mean_image };
Mat HSV_mean = Mat(1, 3, CV_32F, HSV_mean_data);
multiply(pca, HSV_mean, image_pca);

//finding difference with fire_pca 
float diff_fire;
diff_fire = norm(image_pca, fire_pca, NORM_L2);


//finding differene with non_fire_pca
float diff_non_fire;
diff_non_fire = norm(image_pca, nfire_pca, NORM_L2);

if (diff_fire > diff_non_fire)
    putText(Original, "Fire Detected", Point(0, 50), 2, 1, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
else
    putText(Original, "Fire Not Detected", Point(0, 50), 2, 1, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
}
```

[the error that i get when I debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naRry.png)

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog box is reporting that an exception is being thrown. For now the focus should be on understanding where the exception is coming from, why, and what the real problem is with the program. It might not be in the section of code you posted.

Look at the call stack (another window you can open with Visual Studio) and double click up and down the stack to see what your program is doing and why.

Also you can open an exceptions window (Ctl+Alt+E) and disable certain exceptions from breaking (in case there is a handler for the exception).
[image] 
If there is no handler for the exception then you can catch it and see what the details of the exception are.

Take the following simple program for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

void function1()
{
    throw std::exception("My exeption\n");
}

void function2()
{
    function1();
}

int
main()
{
    try {
        function2();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

Visual studio will show this:
[image: example of exception being thrown]

Now in the call stack (top left) we can see that we have `main()` calling `function2()`, calling `function1()` which is throwing the exception.

Finally, if the program continues it will output the text `My exeption` since we caught it in `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

VERY IMPORTANT!

You CANNOT calculate the mean Hue as a linear mean!

HSV is a cylindrical coordinate system. The polar axis is represented by an angle (Hue) and a length (Saturation). The longitudinal axis is a length (Value).

[image: Hue is the angle of a cylindrical coordinate system.]

For instance, if you have a 2 pixels. Pixel 1 has a hue of 0.9. Pixel 2 has a hue of 0.9. Both of these are "reddish" colors. (On the color wheel above, we could say 20 and 340 degrees)

The linear mean is 0.5 is cyan, which is definitely NOT red.

The correct mean is 0.0, which is exactly midway between 0.1 and 0.9 on the color wheel!

The Saturation and Value are both linear axes, and as such, you can calculate their mean very simply:

```
meanSaturation = sum ( s ) / ( rows * cols );
meanValue = sum ( v ) / ( rows * cols );
```

To calculate the mean hue, you must use some trigonometry:

```
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265

void YourFunction ( )
{
  // ... The beginning of the code ...

  // Calculate the sine and cosine of each hue value.
  hueSin = sin ( h / ( 2 * PI ) );
  hueCos = cos ( h / ( 2 * PI ) );

  // Calculate the mean sine and mean cosine.
  hueSinMean = sum ( hueSin ) / ( rows * cols );
  hueCosMean = sum ( hueCos ) / ( rows * cols );

  // Retrieve the mean hue by calculating the mean sine and cosine.
  // This will calculate the mean in radians, on a scale from 0 to 2.
  // Divide by 2 * PI to recover the original scale 
  hueMean = atan2 ( hueCosMean , hueSinMean );

  // Account for negative hue values
  if ( hueMean < 0 )
    hueMean = hueMean + 2 * PI;
  end

  // Convert back to range [ 0 , 1 ].
  hueMean = hueMean / ( 2 * PI );

  // ... The beginning of the code ...
}
```

Comment: Relavant Wikipedia article: [Mean of circular quantities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_circular_quantities).

Comment: Thanks @horchler. Definitely going to add that as a reference in my own code base.